# Can I use core i7 processor for hosting 5-6 web sites?

Tags: configuration, web-hosting, central-processing-unit

Can I use core i7 processor for hosting 5-6 web sites ?

If yes then what other configuration is required?

If No then, which processor is best and cheapest to host 5 to 6 web sites and with what configuration ?

Comment: We need more than just the processor type...the rest of the system specs, type of site, expected site volume, expected site config...something...anything more than just the processor would be useful.

Comment: Depending on the web sites even a 486 might be adequate.

Comment: @John Gardeniers - SX or DX ... :)

Comment: @rtgibbons, an SX would do as there's not a lot of calculating to be done.

Answer (score 2):

A core i7 can run anything from 1,000,000 websites to less than a thousandth of a website. It all depends on the traffic volume you expect to get, and the server-side code involved.

Answer (score 1):

yes, but its overkill unless they are **really** busy sites.

4-+8GB RAM and a Raid 5 with SATA/SAS.

Cheapest config would be an Atom or C7 all-in-one 2-4GB ram with a single sata drive.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume low traffic volume, given the question.

for 5 - 6 sites. I would do something over 600Mhz and 512MB of ram. Anything over 1Ghz and 1GB would be enough to get you going. The reason I'm giving you Mhz and MB instead of a processor is I'm assuming your are looking at hosting servers provided by a hosting company.

Sites like VPS.Net, rackspace cloud, and (mt) all sell based on the speed of the machine, and less on the type of processor.